# Find radiuses that cover a specified point (for a MySQL query)

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, geocoding

Given a specified location I am looking for all the points that have a radiuses coving that point.

For example, lets say I have a database pull of pizza places, and they all deliver various distances (3mi, 10mi, 20mi, even a few 100mi, direct line will be fine for this). I put an address in and it searches this database to find all the locations that have a deliver radius covering my address.

The goal is to be able to search and list a display, so plotting radiuses on a map and seeing what covers is not a particularly good option. Initially I was thinking of plotting the distances as simple squares but the difference at 100mi is 41mi, large enough that it's a concern and hopefully there is a better option.

This is all going to be processed on a PHP site with a MySQL database. I've seen lots of resources on doing the opposite (find all points within a single radius) but nothing for this particular case.

Unlike the duplicate item this has been marked as I need to be able to have it use a radius attached to the points searched against, not a radius from the point it's searching from.

Comment: If geolocation is too fancy, you can use Pythagoras' law, which might also be good enough for formulae like these, but you will have the trouble of converting geolocations to miles.

Comment: The duplicate is not really a duplicate of the problem I have.